# SignalR - Establishing Connection Taking quite a long time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr.client

I have just started working with SignalR for realtime update. I need to perform some operation after the connection is established. so I have written that code in .done() method.

The issue I am facing is :  establishing connection takes some time and due to that I am not able to perform the operation which I am intended to. Following code snippet of my js.

```
   $(function () {
   // Proxy created on the fly  
    projectHub = $.connection.projectHub;
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    // Start the connection
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $("#lnkFollowProject").live("click", function () {
        console.log("Follow click");
        projectHub.server.followProject(projectId, currentLoggedInUserId);
     });
     $(".lnkUnfollowProject").live("click", function () {
        console.log("Unfollow click");
        projectHub.server.unfollowProject(projectId, currentLoggedInUserId);
      });     });     });
```

I am not sure why it is taking time to establish connection. As i tried with simple chat application and it works well. I am doing many other functionality for that page and also using knockout for binding. (not for the above functionality). I have also searched this and found antivirus can be victim. I tried disabling that too but no gain.

I know one solution that I can disable button til connection is establish and on done enable it. But i don't want user to restrict.

Please update me if any other probable issues.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have two suggestions about the code performance.

1) Use .on() method instead of .live()

Using the .live() method is no longer recommended since the later versions of jQuery offer .delegate and .on methods.
    the following issues arise with the use of .live():

I) jQuery attempts to retrieve the elements specified by the selector before calling the .live() method, which may be time-consuming on large documents.

II) Since all .live() events are attached at the document element, events take the longest and slowest possible path before they are handled.

2）  Take click events out of .done() method, because "followProject" and "unfollowProject" methods both need click event to tiger themselves first.

See below code:

```
$(function () {
            // Proxy created on the fly  
            projectHub = $.connection.projectHub;
            $.connection.hub.logging = true;
            // Start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start();

            $(document.body).on("click","#lnkFollowProject", function () {
               console.log("Follow click");
               projectHub.server.followProject(projectId, currentLoggedInUserId);
           });
           $(document.body).on("click",".lnkUnfollowProject", function () {    
               console.log("Unfollow click");
               projectHub.server.unfollowProject(projectId, currentLoggedInUserId);
           });       
        });
```

Comment: initially it was like this only. but issue is if follow/unfollow is clicked - we are using Hub method call which requires connection to be established. So if connection is not established its going to give error saying "SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized."

Comment: The likely cause I found is, we are loading many JS and css files for this page. when we removing them, connection is getting established in milliseconds. But we cant avoid those JS and css files.

Comment: Glad you find the problem. I'm not sure from what you said first, it looked like it's better to use Persistent Connection for the hub. To solve loading many JS and CSS files, the only way I can think of is to use minification.

Comment: I wanted to say from my first comment is, I have implemented initially in the same manner as the code given by you. But if we subscribe the clicks before connection is getting established; in that case if someone clicks the button they going to get error saying "SignalR: Connection has not been fully initialized" in console. as in that click we calling HUB method and connection is still not established.

Comment: I have yet not found solution. its just i  my tried removing all JS and tried establishing it and it worked. I can try minifying them. Lets see how it works.