# SignalR connection is endless

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a signalR connection working but something very weird happens, sometimes it works perfectly in very few seconds and other times when I track the request it took more than 10 minutes trying to connect and it gives me something like that

[image]

can anyone give me an explanation for this? any hints, how to search for the problem

Comment: i think this can help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190568/signalr-establishing-connection-taking-quite-a-long-time

Comment: https://www.google.com.eg/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=NEsPU77GH87Q8geVrIHgDw&gws_rd=cr#q=+signalR+connection+take+too+long

Answer (score 2):

The request your looking at: `/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&...` is supposed to be endless.

SingalR is using [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) technology called [server-sent events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) or SSE. The basic idea is that SignalR responds to SSE requests in chunks, but never actually closes the response unless the client asks it to.

Browsers with SSE support can read the chunks sent from the server as they are sent even though the response doesn't end. This allows an unlimited number of messages to be sent in response to a single request.

Comment: but the thing is that it is endless but doesn't listen to any notifications, for example I can have four tabs opened in same browser, two will receive notifications and the other two won't.
do you know why this can happen?